# browser support for tap-highlight-color

Tags: css, cross-browser

What is the browser support for the CSS3 rule `tap-highlight-color`?

I have seen that it works for the **webkit based** using the webkit prefix: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color`.
I myself does currently only have the webkit prefix rule on my site, and it is supported by the following devices I have tried:

- Google Chrome v. 34.0.1847.131 (iMac)
- Google Chrome v. 34.0.1847.114 (Samsung Galaxy S4)
- Android Browser v. 1.5 (Samsung Galaxy S4)

It doesn't work on:

- Android Browser (Samsung GT-I9100)

But is it somehow possible to get support for Mozilla, Microsoft or any of the not **webkit based** browsers?

Comment: I don't think `tap-highlight-color` is part of CSS3.

Comment: @BoltClock, so it's only an additional feature which Chrome have added? Cause in that case I just tested in on `Firefox v. 29.0 (Samsung Galaxy S4)` which it works as well using the `-webkit-`-prefix.